# Share UILocalnotification between devices

Tags: core-data, swift, notifications, icloud

I'm developing an ToDo app, and I'm planning to use UILocalNotification. I have integrated CoreData with iCloud support.

I have searched a lot on Google how to share the notifications between the devices, but I can't find anything. 
So i hope some of you people out there can help a new Swift developere here, so my question is:

1: Can i share notifications between devices without using a server to send push notifications?
2: How many NSLocalnotification can i have on a device?

//Kim

Comment: Do you by chance mean `UILocalNotification`?

Comment: You can try with UIActivity and UIActivityViewController to share  text, images, or other contents. Plese see [UIActivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/index.html) for information

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Core Data with iCloud to keep the data in sync between devices you can somewhat achieve what your after. What you would need to do is detect when new changes are imported from iCloud and refresh the notifications at that point. I have used that approach successfully before but it does come with a few caveats. In particular:
 - Without storing additional information the same notification will be shown on multiple devices.
 - The synchronising of the notifications is reliant on the iCloud data being updated. This means that without a means to refresh the iCloud data in the background other devices will not be in sync. It may be possible to work around this using an extension or background services but I'm not too familiar with them.